# quick java question, how to make code silent

Tags: java, sorting

I have to run this code against a tester and it needs to be silent(if that makes sense) since is going against a lot of data if it printed everything my computer would crash.

I have no idea how to make it return silent values.

```
public static void uniqueCharacters(String test){
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++){
        char current = test.charAt(i);
        if (temp.indexOf(current) < 0){
            temp = temp + current;
        } else {
            temp = temp.replace(String.valueOf(current), "");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(temp + " ");

}

//// here's the tester I'm using 

@Test
    public void testUniqueCharacters() {
        Random rng = new Random(SEED);
        CRC32 check = new CRC32(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
            int len = rng.nextInt(100) + (2 << rng.nextInt(5));
            String s = buildString(rng, len);
            String res = P2J2.uniqueCharacters(s);
            check.update(res.getBytes());
        }    
        assertEquals(3756363171L, check.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: 'Be silent' means  don't print to console ?

Comment: Why is it printing it in the first place and not returning the String value?

Comment: I don't see that your tester will even compile, since it expects ```uniqueCharacters``` to return a value, and the ```uniqueCharacters``` you show is declared void.  I assume those two are supposed to be the same routine.

Comment: I also don't see how you can apparently expect to feed in random inputs and get a predetermined checksum as a result. But that's based on guessing what for example ```buildString(rng,len)``` does.  Even though its only pseudorandom and thus repeatable, the expected checksum has to come from somewhere.  Was it hand-calculated?

Comment: Does my answer answers your problem ?

Comment: you may think about accepting an answer now ;)

Answer (score 2):

To be *silent* (if means no print) and in fact **get your code working** you need to return the value you compute, and not print it :

```
static String uniqueCharacters(String test){
    String temp = "";
    //...
    return temp;
}
```

---

I'd also want to suggest another way to it : read each char, and if it appears ater in the string, remove all instances

```
static String uniqueCharacters(String test) {
    String res = test;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        char current = test.charAt(i);
        if (test.indexOf(current, i + 1) >= 0) 
            res = res.replaceAll(current + "", "");
    }
    return res;
}
```